# expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "proj1.h"
using namespace std;

//Deciphers a message. cip[] is a char array containing a Cipher message                                                            
//as a null-term.                                                                                                                   
void Decipher(char Cip[], char key);
{
  char intCip[];
  char intMessage[];
  char cipher[];
  int intKey = key - 'A';
  for( int i = 0; i < strlen(Cip); i++)
    {
      if(Cip[i] >= 'A' && Cip[i] <= 'Z')
        {
          intCip[i] = key - Cip[i];
        }
    }
  for( int i = 0; i < strlen(Cip); i++)
    {
      Cip[i] = (intCip[i] + (intKey % 26));
    }
}

char SolveCipher(const char Cip[], char dec[]);
{
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  Decipher (ciper[0], 'R');
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error message when I try to make the .exe

```
g++ -Wall proj1.cpp -o program
proj1.cpp:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

What does this mean? I can't see what I would need before the '{' since that starts the function definition.

Comment: you have semicolon in this function definition: `char SolveCipher(const char Cip[], char dec[]);` it doesnt belong there

Comment: It means that the semicolon at the end of the "void Decipher(...)" line is confusing the compiler, and you should remove the semicolon from that line.

Comment: After you fix your semicolon typos I suspect your next question will be why `char intCip[];` doesn't compile. Do you have a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from?

Comment: which strange unreadable indentation style is this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after `void Decipher(char Cip[], char key)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a ; after SolveCipher definition which is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Decipher(char Cip[], char key); // notice the semicolon
```

This means a function prototype declaration. To define a function you need to remove the semicolon